# Java: abstract generic class and method overloading order

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, overloading

Look at this class

```
abstract class LolCat<T> {
    T execute() throws Err, Arr {
        T lol = doSomething();
        if (lol == null)
            lol = doSomething();

        return lol;
     }

    abstract T doSomething();
    abstract T doSomething() throws Err, Arr;
}
```

Now we have an anonymous implementation in some whatever method somewhere, of the LolCat like this

```
final UhmLetsSayCat cat = new ImplLolCat<UhmLetsSayCat>() {
    @Override
    UhmLetsSayCat doSomething() {
        return null; // somehow a UhmLetsSayCat is returned for real sometimes null
    }

    @Override
    UhmLetsSayCat doSomething() throws Err,Arr {
        return null; // really it does right thing, whatever
    }
 }.execute();
```

Now my question is, how come the first call to doSomething() goes to the method that does not throw Err,Arr but the second call, if lol is null, runs the doSomething implementation which throws Err,Arr. How is this distinction made between which methods to run!?

EDIT: FALSE ALARM. OMG. I must have been blind the whole evening, doSomething is actually not the same method names, they where called querryAll and QuerryAl1, im gonna find the guy who did it and smack him.

EDIT2: Thanks everyone.

Comment: It doesn't compile: duplicate method doSomething() in type LolCat<T>. My guess is that in your real code, the method signatures (name or arguments) are different.

Comment: This is the class I have that does compile. It is actually an abstract class LolCat<T> inside a public class Something. Does that make a difference? And the anonymous implementation is in a method in Something.

Comment: Seconded. I get 'already defined...'

Comment: The compiler having headache seeing your code.

Comment: Trim down the code to the maximum (but not more), post it here, and tell us which compiler, JDK and version you use. The above doesn't compile.

Comment: Embarrassed to say... I didnt see it was different method names, somebody left the real names as queryAll and queryAl1, wtf! ARHG.

Comment: Use `svn blame` to find the culprit, and go tell him what you think of his naming choices.

Comment: Proper naming is a key of success.

Comment: @Antonioo Look at the bright side it wasnt queryAlI. (the second one is an uppercase i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have two methods with the same signature declared in a class. The `throws` clause , annotations and return type don't count.

```
abstract T doSomething();
abstract T doSomething() throws Err, Arr; // won't compile
```

If this compiles, there is a bug in your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even be able to compile this example (error: duplicate method `doSomething()`)

Comment: Sorry but this is comment, not solution

Comment: In my opinion this is a solution because the problem can't even exist

Comment: OK, looking at it this way you might be right. My twisted logic "if there is no real problem at the first place-> there is no real solution" failed me :)